# How to get C/C++ function name from Perforce diff between two version

Tags: python, c++, c, perforce

I am trying to extract diff between to perforce revision files. But my requirement is to extract function names which got modified. Is there a way to find changed functions.

Comment: Afaik perforce can't do that for you. Fetch both versions and diff them should work though.

Comment: You may have to actually "parse" (I use the term relatively loosely) the source file to do that. Get the whole source file, scan backwards from the diff-point until you find the function declaration. Coding style will probably help you here, so you may be able to identify a function from "it's starting at column 1 and has parenthesis", for example.

Comment: @Mats Petersson, Thank you. By the above way I am able to parse and extract Function changed.

Answer (score 0):

Do `p4 diff2` and grep with a regex that matches function names:

[Regex to pull out C function prototype declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476173/regex-to-pull-out-c-function-prototype-declarations)